# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'wineship'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, minecraft

I've scoured similar questions looking for a solution to my problem since a lot of people are having the same issue as me. However, none of the solutions are helping, and I still have the same error stack.

This is my java code that starts the connection. The stack clearly points to the line that says conn=DriverManager.getConnection(...);:

```
package com.wine.plugins.managers.models;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public abstract class DatabaseModel 
{
    protected static Connection conn = null;

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/wineships?useSSL=false";
    private static final String username = "wineship";
    private static final String password = "password";

    public DatabaseModel()
    {
        try {
            if(conn == null)
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                if (conn != null) {
                    System.out.println("Connected to the database");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the stack:

```
[08:24:25 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'wineship'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[08:24:25 WARN]: at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2194)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2225)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.wine.plugins.managers.models.DatabaseModel.<init>(DatabaseModel.java:21)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.wine.plugins.managers.models.ValidBlocksDatabaseModel.<init>(ValidBlocksDatabaseModel.java:10)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.wine.plugins.managers.BlockValidityManager.initialize(BlockValidityManager.java:16)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at com.wine.plugins.WineShips.onEnable(WineShips.java:12)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:402)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:377)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:327)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:421)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:382)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:337)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:272)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:544)
[08:24:25 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The MySQL server is running on localhost:3306 on the program Xampp on Linux. The code is for a minecraft server that will request data from the SQL server.

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead?

Comment: Make sure that you have a user 'wineship'@'localhost' that have the necessary privileges to your database.

Comment: Maybe you don't have user called `wineship` and password as `password`. Try with `root` as user and `""` (no password simply open and close double quotes) as password. Because these are the default user name and password if not configured your user name and passwords yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been tinkering with phpmyadmin, and I've found that entering in an address, instead of using '%', solved my problem. I also changed "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 @nigel ren

My code is now:

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/wineships";
private static final String username = "wineship";
private static final String password = "password";
```